# Помогите разобраться с qmake

Tags: c++, qmake

Решил перейти от `cmake` к `qmake` и тут же напоролся на такую проблему: как написать `.pro`-файл для компиляции проги с двумя создаваемыми библиотеками? Тобишь, имеется некий проект с папками `sources` и `include` - в `include`, конечно, хэдэры, а в `sources` две папки: `libs` и `liba`. Каждая из них содержит `.cpp` файлы для компиляции соответствующих библиотек. Примерный `CMakeLists.txt` у меня:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(alfa)

set(SRC_MAIN sources/main.cpp)
set(LIBRARY_A "a")
file(GLOB SRC_A "sources/liba/*.cpp")
set(LIBRARY_S "s")
file(GLOB SRS_S "sources/libs/*.cpp")

set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER clang++)
add_definitions(-Wall -std=c++14)

include_directories(include)

add_library(${LIBRARY_A} SHARED ${SRC_A})
add_library(${LIBRARY_S} SHARED ${SRC_S})

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC_MAIN})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${LIBRARY_A} ${LIBRARY_S})
```

Я, к сожалению, не понял как в одном `.pro`-файле задать цели для компиляции программы и библиотек - нужны разные `.pro`-файлы на каждую библиотеку? Как сделать подобное коду выше в `qmake`?

Comment: Там вроде можно подпроекты делать. У вас тогда в одном подпроекте будет одна библиотека, а в другом - другая. Даже [пруф](https://wiki.qt.io/SUBDIRS_-_handling_dependencies) есть вроде

Comment: вы про `SUBDIRS`? Я видел эту опцию, но как объеденить - не нашел примеров

Comment: Пример по ссылке не подойдёт ? Цитат оттуда `# what subproject depends on others app.depends = lib lib2`

Comment: @vegorov пока не знаю: пытаюсь адаптировать, но сново уперся - выставление стандарта компиляции реализовано не понятно как. Ставлю `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS = -std=c++14` так у меня сразу два стандарта вываливается: указанный и 11-й!

Comment: Там вроде от версии qt зависело, в пятом там другой флаг, указанный вами из qt4 вроде

Comment: можете глянуть как реализована сборка QT на SUBDIRS

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch  `CONFIG += c++14` начиная с Qt 5.4

Comment: Переходить с qmake на CMake это ошибка. qmake мёртв, тогда как CMake это живой и быстро развивающийся проект. Обычно переходы происходят как раз обратные. Если же очень не нравится CMake и хочется чего-то QT-специфичного, то лучше посмотреть в сторону QBS (сам не пробовал)

Comment: @ixSci решил перейти к qmake просто потому, что он, как правило, всегда сопутствует QT, который я начинаю изучать. Но, учитывая последний опыт использования qmake думаю реально не стоит. Единствнная проблема с cmake это отсутствие литературы по нему на русском, благо много чего есть на форумах по нему.

Comment: Да, с документацией по CMake действительно плохо, но для базового использования достаточно некоторой базы. Которую потихоньку Вы будете расширять.

Comment: Люди, давайте тему CMake здесь развивать, а то и в правду не хорошо.

Comment: Тем более QtCreator вполне нормально поддерживает проекты на CMake. Мы на работе тоже с qmake на cmake перешли.

Comment: @vegorov я не пользуюсь QtCreator, да и вообще IDE. Я юзаю vim c плагинами прямо из командной строки

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch сурово однако